# Android Log.w(), Log.d(), Log.i() not printing

Tags: android, logging

```
Log.i("test","why");
Log.e("test","why");
Log.d("test","why");
Log.w("test","why");
```

Why aren't `Log.i`, `Log.d` printing?

[image]

Comment: Is the phone problem ，use another phone is ok

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your display level in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: yes, i choosed  ,but  not showing

Answer (score 0):

What's your log level set to?

Set it to Verbose to view all log messages

[image]

Comment: it,s verbose  but not showing